# How to remove fragment the replaced fragment in fragment transition?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have made a `NavigationDrawer` fragment in which have items as `Home`, `Settings`, `Feedback` and few. The `home` item when clicked the home should open where home is the initial page that opens on app start.

The process to open pages onclick of the item that i am using is that i am replacing the `layout` with other fragment with this piece of code

```
 if (fragment != null) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.relative, fragment).commit();
                menuList.setItemChecked(position, true);
                menuList.setSelection(position);
                getActivity().setTitle(ittems[position]);
```

Well all works fine expect one, when i try to click the `home` button how do i go to the initial/starting page?

What i have done is on clicking `home` item i am initialising the `intent` and starting the `activity`, but i don't like it as its an `activity` and when you call activity it closes the drawer abruptly, unlike the smooth closing of the drawer using the replacement process that i have used for all other items, also when it goes back it feels like the app has been restarted.

So i want to know is there a way to go back to the initial page or cancel the fragment transition replacement layout?

**updated with the codes**

```
 menuList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (position) {

                case 0:Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                    getActivity().overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Bundle overview = new Bundle();
                    overview.putInt("overview", finalPage);
                    overview.putInt("month", tm+1);
                    overview.putInt("year", ty);
                    fragment = new OverviewFragment();
                    fragment.setArguments(overview);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    fragment = new StatisticsFragment();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    fragment= new SomeFragment();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    fragment = new SettingsFragment();
                    break;
                case 5:fragment= new FeedbackFragment();
                    break;
            }
            if (fragment != null) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.relative, fragment).commit();
                menuList.setItemChecked(position, true);
                menuList.setSelection(position);
                getActivity().setTitle(ittems[position]);
            }
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.START);
        }
    });
```

> **SOLVED**

After a hard day of researching i got a solution to this problem.. I'm posting it here incase any one is looking for it

Here is what i have done

```
        menuList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            FragmentTransaction fragmentManager = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager1= getFragmentManager();
            switch (position) {

                case 0:
                    while (fragmentManager1.getBackStackEntryCount()!=0){
                        fragmentManager1.popBackStackImmediate();
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Bundle overview = new Bundle();
                    overview.putInt("overview", finalPage);
                    overview.putInt("month", tm+1);
                    overview.putInt("year", ty);
                    fragment = new OverviewFragment();
                    fragment.setArguments(overview);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    fragment = new StatisticsFragment();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    fragment= new SomeFragment();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    fragment = new SettingsFragment();
                    break;
                case 5:fragment= new FeedbackFragment();
                    break;
            }
            if (fragment != null) {
                fragmentManager.addToBackStack("back");
                fragmentManager
                        .replace(R.id.relative, fragment).commit();
                menuList.setItemChecked(position, true);
                menuList.setSelection(position);
                getActivity().setTitle(ittems[position]);
            }
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.START);
        }
    });
```

The concept that i tried here is i am putting all the fragments to the backstack and when the `home` item is clicked i am clearing the complete backstack

Comment: please post your complete navigation drawer code.

Comment: again call the same code  piece, with home fragment instance, on home item click

Comment: @AbhishekDabral it will return fragment as `null` for the first time as there's no `onClick` event has been called

Comment: @Meenaxi currently i am out will surely updated it sooner

Comment: Is your home item  a fragmentt?

Comment: no sir its an activity class

Comment: MainActivity is your another activity Or the the activity itself which conntain drawer?

Comment: no `MainActivity` is another activity

Answer (score 0):

Put this code to Back or Home button
Also you can put it to  @override method onBackPressed(). 
Hope this helps you :)

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
<CurrentFragmane> fragment = (<CurrentFragmane>) getFragmentManager()
.findFragmentByTag("<CurrentFragmane>");
fragmentTransaction.remove(fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

Comment: but for tagging the fragment i need to have tag, where in my case i just want to go back to the home of my app, which is not a fragment

Comment: This code remove the current fragment 
but if you are using Activity as your Home Page of an activity you can use FragmentActivity for it.

Comment: that's the problem i can't make it `fragmentActivity` for some reason